# flutter compressing images resolves in bad quality

Tags: flutter, image-compression

I am using [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) to compress images. I wrote a method that takes a fileSize and tries to reduce the image down to that fileSize with best quality. Here is the method:

```
Future<File?> compressImage(File image, {int kb = 50}) async {
    var inPath = image.absolute.path;
    int q = 95;
    File? result = image;
    while (q >= 1 && result != null && (await result.length() > kb * 1024)) {
      result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        inPath,
        outPath,
        quality: q,
        minHeight: 1500,
        minWidth: 1500,
      );
      q = q ~/ 2;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

So basically this method checks whether the image is already smaller than the given size, and if not, compresses the image down. For every run, the quality gets reduces by 50%, until it is 1.
This method works, but I get very different image qualities for the same sizes on my iPhone and Android Phone.

on my iPhone (iPhone 11, iOS 15.5), I can compress the image down to 50kb and the quality is perfect, I don't see any difference. On my Android Phone (Samsung Galaxy A13, Android 12), if I compress the image down to 50kb, the quality is pretty bad.

Android Example:
initial length: 1213154
compress quality: 47
compressed length: 89085

iOS Example:
initial length: 1409313
compress quality: 2
compressed length: 76801

So, in the iOS example, I set had to use a quality of 2 to get it down to about 76kb and the result is perfect. On Android, I used a quality of 47 to get it down to 89kb, and the quality is pretty bad.

Is there a method how I can reduce the size as much as possible without really loosing quality of the image? Are there any other factors I missed? This does not really make sense to me, because the image on iOS is way better even though it is compressed to a way lower file size.

Answer (score 0):

The package seems to provide native code written in Kotlin (for Android) and Swift (for iOS). So there may be differences between those two implementations, or even a bug in the Android code leading to worse quality.

You could file an [issue](https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_image_compress/issues) on their github page.